# center Slideshow text html

Tags: html, css, text, slideshow, responsive

I am trying to make the text in the slideshow stop closer to the left margin, always on the middle of the grey area  both horizontally and vertically . Also as you may see when the texts goes away the x scrollbar grows and black space shows to ur right. Would anybody know whats the problem I can t seem to figure it out and I ll appreciate very much your help.

Also in the responsive mode a black area shows up to your right and I m not sure if it is related to the slideshow or to another mistake?

thanks and looking forward to your answer

here is the web online http://vtwg.eu/ZMT/untitled3.html
and u can find the code below
victoria

```css
#gifphrases1 { 
    font-family: arial;
    background: grey;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 180px;
    background-image: url("back.png");
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    }

    .item-1, 
    .item-2, 
    .item-3 {
    padding: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 90%;
    font-size: 1.6em;
    animation-duration: 20s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    text-align: center;


    }

    .item-1{
    animation-name: anim-1;

    }

    .item-2{
    animation-name: anim-2;
    }

    .item-3{
    animation-name: anim-3;
    }




    @keyframes anim-1 {
    0%, 8.3% { left: -100%; opacity: 0; }
    8.3%,25% { left: 25%; opacity: 1; }
    33.33%, 100% { left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
    }

    @keyframes anim-2 {
    0%, 33.33% { left: -100%; opacity: 0; }
    41.63%, 58.29% { left: 25%; opacity: 1; }
    66.66%, 100% { left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
    }

    @keyframes anim-3 {
    0%, 66.66% { left: -100%; opacity: 0; }
    74.96%, 91.62% { left: 25%; opacity: 1; }
    100% { left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
    }
```

```html
<center>
<div id="gifphrases1">

    <p class="item-1">If you're ever in Buenos Aires, ZZK Music Tours are an expert on the local music scene and generous with their knowledge. <br>    <b>Marc Hogan - Pitchfork</b> </p>

    <p class="item-2">With deep and real relationships with local artists and venues, ZZK was able to show me a time that would otherwise be impossible when first coming to the city. If you’re a lover of music, culture, nightlife and want to be immediately connected when coming into a new city, ZZK has your back. <br><b>Aerosyn-Lex Mestrovic - Visual Artist</b> </p>

    </p>

    <p class="item-3">From sweaty late night tango dancing at underground milongas, to religious theme parks complete with volcanic eruptions, to some of the best grilled steaks I've ever eaten I have ZZK to thank!<br>            <b>Jeffrey Paradise - Poolside</b>         </p>
</div>
</center>
```

Comment: Fix your code errors in addition to the below answer. https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fvtwg.eu%2FZMT%2Funtitled3.html <center> is deprecated so use css for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could just update your @keyframes.
Define the "left" values as "-100%", "0%" and "100%" for each your @keyframes.

```
@keyframes anim-1 {
  0%, 8.3% { left: -100%; opacity: 0; }
  8.3%,25% { left: 0%; opacity: 1; }
  33.33%, 100% { left: 100%; opacity: 0; }
}

@keyframes anim-2 {
  0%, 33.33% { left: -100%; opacity: 0; }
  41.63%, 58.29% { left: 0%; opacity: 1; }
  66.66%, 100% { left: 100%; opacity: 0; }
}

@keyframes anim-3 {
  0%, 66.66% { left: -100%; opacity: 0; }
  74.96%, 91.62% { left: 0%; opacity: 1; }
  100% { left: 100%; opacity: 0; }
}
```

**Edit #1**:
`margin-top: 0;` could be added to each ".item-#" to empty the space above each of them.

**Edit #2**:
I've found that adding `position: relative` to "#gifphrases1" fixed the `overflow: hidden` rule from malfunctioning.
However, you have to watch out for the height of your #gifphrases1 element. I set it to 400px using the `height: 400px` in my example below (see the code snippet).

**Edit #3**:
Now that I think about it, adding `position: relative` to "#gifphrases1" allows you to make the vertical centering you wanted!
Add the `top: 50%` rule to the items – that will place them below the middle of the parent element.
Now, adding `transform: translate(0, -50%)` will change that, and place the middle of each item on the middle of the parent element. **Perfectly centered!** ← that what matters

```css
#gifphrases1 { 
  font-family: arial;
  background: grey;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 400px;
  background-image: url("back.png");
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin-left: 0px;

}

.item-1, 
.item-2, 
.item-3 {
  margin-top: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  display: block;
  width: 90%;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  animation-duration: 20s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  text-align: center;
}

.item-1 {
  animation-name: anim-1;
}
.item-2 {
  animation-name: anim-2;
}
.item-3 {
  animation-name: anim-3;
}

@keyframes anim-1 {
  0%, 8.3% { left: -100%; opacity: 0; }
  8.3%,25% { left: 0%; opacity: 1; }
  33.33%, 100% { left: 100%; opacity: 0; }
}

@keyframes anim-2 {
  0%, 33.33% { left: -100%; opacity: 0; }
  41.63%, 58.29% { left: 0%; opacity: 1; }
  66.66%, 100% { left: 100%; opacity: 0; }
}

@keyframes anim-3 {
    0%, 66.66% { left: -100%; opacity: 0; }
    74.96%, 91.62% { left: 0%; opacity: 1; }
    100% { left: 100%; opacity: 0; }
}
```

```html
<center>
<div id="gifphrases1">

    <p class="item-1">If you're ever in Buenos Aires, ZZK Music Tours are an expert on the local music scene and generous with their knowledge. <br>    <b>Marc Hogan - Pitchfork</b> </p>

    <p class="item-2">With deep and real relationships with local artists and venues, ZZK was able to show me a time that would otherwise be impossible when first coming to the city. If you’re a lover of music, culture, nightlife and want to be immediately connected when coming into a new city, ZZK has your back. <br><b>Aerosyn-Lex Mestrovic - Visual Artist</b> </p>

    <p class="item-3">From sweaty late night tango dancing at underground milongas, to religious theme parks complete with volcanic eruptions, to some of the best grilled steaks I've ever eaten I have ZZK to thank!<br>            <b>Jeffrey Paradise - Poolside</b>         </p>
</div>
</center>
```

Comment: Dear Matiboux, thanks so much for your answer was very helpful. The only thing I couldn t solve is the black space that shows up to your right of the whole screen when the phrase is fading away. This space appears and disappears with the phrase. 
Also I need to add 4 more phrases and I ve been trying different ways but I can t achieve a decent result do you have any ideas? best regards and thanks. V

Comment: Sorry for the late comment – Anyway, I've found that adding `position: relative;` to "#gifphrases1" fixed the `overflow: hidden` from malfunctioning. However, you have to watch out for the height of your #gifphrases1 element..

Comment: Also, now that I think about it, adding `position: relative` to "#gifphrases1" allows you to do the vertical centering you wanted! I updated my post with a little explanation for you, see Edit #3 <3 (lemme time to do the edit tho)

Comment: Done, let me know when you see what I added and if that works for you!

Comment: Dear Matiboux! this works perfectly thanks so much for your help I appreaciate it very much. I have one last question but I don t wanna abuse your good will! haha! So feel free to just skip it. To finish wiht the web I need to ad 4 more phrases to the slideshow. I ve been trying with different ways but nothing seem to works correctly. The last one I tried Is just ading and item 4 ...and increasing the values in the keyframes but the result is no good. Here is the code.

Comment: oh nooo.. I didn't checked StackOverFlow for a whiiiile. I just saw your comment right now.

Comment: Anyway, here's my idea : maybe you should – in addition to shortening the keyframes – increase your `animation-duration` rule.
Finally, that would be like : if doubling the items, also double the duration so that 10% becomes 5% in keyframes. The result would be similar to how is it right now, I think.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that I notice is that you have another `</p>` tag after your `<p class="item-2"></p>`

Next this is all of your HTML working:

```
    <center>
  <div id="gifphrases1">
    <p class="item-1">
      If you're ever in Buenos Aires, ZZK Music Tours are an expert on the local music scene and generous with their knowledge. 
      <br>    
      <b>Marc Hogan - Pitchfork</b> 
    </p>
    <p class="item-2">
      With deep and real relationships with local artists and venues, ZZK was able to show me a time that would otherwise be impossible when first coming to the city. If you’re a lover of music, culture, nightlife and want to be immediately connected when coming into a new city, ZZK has your back. 
      <br>
      <b>Aerosyn-Lex Mestrovic - Visual Artist</b> 
    </p>
  <p class="item-3">
    From sweaty late night tango dancing at underground milongas, to religious theme parks complete with volcanic eruptions, to some of the best grilled steaks I've ever eaten I have ZZK to thank!
    <br>            
    <b>Jeffrey Paradise - Poolside</b> 
  </p>
  </div>
</center>
```

And your CSS

```
#gifphrases1 { 
    font-family: arial;
    background: grey;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 180px;
    background-image: url("back.png");
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    }

    .item-1, 
    .item-2, 
    .item-3 {
    padding: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 90%;
    font-size: 1.6em;
    animation-duration: 20s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    text-align: center;


    }

    .item-1{
    animation-name: anim-1;

    }

    .item-2{
    animation-name: anim-2;
    }

    .item-3{
    animation-name: anim-3;
    }




    @keyframes anim-1 {
    0%, 8.3% { left: -100%; opacity: 0; }
    8.3%,25% { left: 0%; opacity: 1; }
    33.33%, 100% { left: 100%; opacity: 0; }
    }

    @keyframes anim-2 {
    0%, 33.33% { left: -100%; opacity: 0; }
    41.63%, 58.29% { left: 0%; opacity: 1; }
    66.66%, 100% { left: 100%; opacity: 0; }
    }

    @keyframes anim-3 {
    0%, 66.66% { left: -100%; opacity: 0; }
    74.96%, 91.62% { left: 0%; opacity: 1; }
    100% { left: 100%; opacity: 0; }
    }
```

Comment: You could improve the quality of your Answer by mentioning if the extra `</p>` was the only problem you encountered, and if not, then explaining what other modifications you made and why  This will educate the Questioner (and potentially anybody else reading this) and better enable them to be prepared for similar situations in the future in addition to providing corrected code.